# JSoup Strip html markup from xml

Tags: java, html, jsoup

i've been looking stackoverflow but couldn't get anyone with this kind of problem.

I want to do something like this:

Input String:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<List>
  <Object>
    <Section>Fruit</Section>
    <Category>Bananas</Category>
    <Brand>Chiquita</Brand>
    <Obs><p>
Vende-se a pe&ccedil;as ou o conjunto.</p><br>
    </Obs>
  </Object>
</List>
```

What i want is to strip html tags, like `<p>,<br>` etc. So it ends like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<List>
  <Object>
    <Section>Fruit</Section>
    <Category>Bananas</Category>
    <Brand>Chiquita</Brand>
    <Obs>
Vende-se a pe&ccedil;as ou o conjunto.
    </Obs>
  </Object>
</List>
```

I have been playing around with JSoup, but i can't seem to make it work properly.

This is the code i have:

```
Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none();
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><List><Object><Section>Fruit</Section><Category>Bananas</Category><Brand>Chiquita</Brand><Obs><p>Vende-se a pe&ccedil;as ou o conjunto.</p><br></Obs></Object></List>";

whitelist.addTags(new String[]{"?xml", "List", "Object", "Section", "Category", "Brand", "Obs"});
String safe = Jsoup.clean(xml, whitelist);
```

This is the result i am obtaining:

```
FruitBananasChiquitaVende-se a pe&ccedil;as ou o conjunto.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tags are lowercased, use:

```
whitelist.addTags(new String[] { "?xml", "list", "object", "section",
    "category", "brand", "obs" });
```

output:

```
<list>
 <object>
  <section>
   Fruit
  </section>
  <category>
   Bananas
  </category>
  <brand>
   Chiquita
  </brand>
  <obs>
   Vende-se a pe&ccedil;as ou o conjunto.
  </obs></object>
</list>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly :)

Was that info on the documentation? Today was the first time i used jsoup, maybe i missed that info.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe somwhere, but not easy to see. Btw. a good source for documentation (beside javadoc and website) is the *source code* - or Stackoverflow :-D

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unwrap()` to do so:

**Example:**

```
    final String input = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n"
            + "<List>\n"
            + "  <Object>\n"
            + "    <Section>Fruit</Section>\n"
            + "    <Category>Bananas</Category>\n"
            + "    <Brand>Chiquita</Brand>\n"
            + "    <Obs><p>\n"
            + "Vende-se a pe&ccedil;as ou o conjunto.</p><br>\n"
            + "    </Obs>\n"
            + "  </Object>\n"
            + "</List>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "", Parser.xmlParser()); // XML-Parser!

    doc.select("p").unwrap(); // unwrapes all p-tags
    doc.select("br").unwrap(); // uńwraps all br-tags
```

Also it's better to use a **XML-Parser** instead of a *HTML-Parser* here.

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<list> 
 <object> 
  <section>
   Fruit
  </section> 
  <category>
   Bananas
  </category> 
  <brand>
   Chiquita
  </brand> 
  <obs>
    Vende-se a pe&ccedil;as ou o conjunto. 
  </obs> </object> 
</list>
```

Comment: This answer is also correct! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Btw. you can upvote answers which are helpful to you (requires min. 15 Rep.). This also includes answers you've already accepted.